# datatables and bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm wonder which is the best way to create tables by [datatables](https://datatables.net/) or the [bootstrap-table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/)! I mean, I want to know the differences between them, and their advantages in create a table.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

[Bootstrap tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) are the most used data tables because they are responsive and therefor scales for different devices

But if we use normal data tables then we have to write different code for the different resolution screens by using media quires.

so I highly recommend using Bootstrap tables.

Comment: Actually, both are fully compatible with bootstrap. You're referring to tables in bootstrap, not bootstrap-table. I think the question here is "bootstrap-table or datatables?".

Comment: How is Datatables not responsive ? It seems you did not even use it and have no idea what you are saying

Comment: `dataTable` is responsive https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/
the OP means `dataTable` jQuery plugin not just an ordinary `data table` and `bootstrap-table` developed by wenzhixin.